# Google Sheets Centimeters to Inches/Feet

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've been reading a lot of posts on this website this year, and I have to say that I almost always found an answer to my question, so first thanks a lot for all the help you already gave me.

The reason of my first post here is that I can't find a way to convert centimeters to inches or feet in text cells.

[UPDATED]
These are the 5 possibilities for my data :

- 45
- 356 x 160
- (25-28) x (45-49)
- 200 x 77 and 202 x 80
- 202 x 78, 200 x 77 and 202 x 80

I would like to have a formula that can change the number without modifying the rest. A formula that for :

`115-118 x 45-54`

Returns :

`45-46 x 18-21`

Like:

`=ROUND(115/2.54)&"-"&ROUND(118/2.54)&" x "&ROUND(45/2.54)&"-"&ROUND(54/2.54)`

Comment: how reliably consistent are those 3 examples you gave? always separated by an x? sometimes theres a comma? sometimes there's a space?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `CONVERT`function [Doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055540)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&"", "(\d+) x (\d+), (\d+) x (\d+) and (\d+) x (\d+)"),
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,1)&" x "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,2)&", "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,3)&" x "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,4)&" and "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,5)&" x "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,6),
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&"", "(\d+) x (\d+) and (\d+) x (\d+)"),
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,1)&" x "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,2)&" and "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,3)&" x "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,4),
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&"", "(\d+) x (\d+)"), 
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,1)&" x "&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,2),
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&"", "(\(\d+-\d+)\) x \((\d+-\d+)\)"), "("&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,1)&"-"&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,2)&") x ("&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,3)&"-"&
   INDEX(ROUND(CONVERT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\D+", " "), " "), "cm", "in")),,4)&")", 
 ROUND(CONVERT(A2:A*1, "cm", "in"))))))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " ")="",,ROUND(CONVERT(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " "), "cm", "in"))), IFERROR(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " ")))),,999^99)),
 " - ", "-"), "( ", "("), " )", ")"), " , ", ", "))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

I found that if someone needs :

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " ")="",,IF(ROUNDDOWN(CONVERT(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " "), "cm", "ft"))=0,"",ROUNDDOWN(CONVERT(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " "), "cm", "ft"))&"'")&IF(ROUND((CONVERT(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " "), "cm", "ft")-ROUNDDOWN(CONVERT(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " "), "cm", "ft")))*12)=0,"",ROUND((CONVERT(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " "), "cm", "ft")-ROUNDDOWN(CONVERT(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " "), "cm", "ft")))*12)&"""")), IFERROR(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F12,
 "-", " - "), "(", "( "), ")", " )"), ", ", " , "), " ")))),,999^99)),
 " - ", "-"), "( ", "("), " )", ")"), " , ", ", "))
```

For :

```
(115-12) x (34-245), (115-44) x (34-245) and (115-44) x (34-245)
```

Returns :

```
(3'9"-5") x (1'1"-8'), (3'9"-1'5") x (1'1"-8') and (3'9"-1'5") x (1'1"-8')
```